# Как разрешить вводить только цифры ( даже спецсимволы запретить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

сейчас у меня так

```html
<input type="text" class="text">
$('.text').on('input', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]/, ''))
});
```

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, так можно будет вводить +-..  А я пробую разрешить  только цифры

Answer (score 1):

`\D` / `[^\d]` - любой символ, кроме десятичной цифры

```js
$('.text').on('input', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/, ''))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text">
```